# Javascript variables within attributes

Tags: php, javascript

With php it's easy to do something like this

```
<?
$x = "Joe";
echo "My name is $x";

?>
```

But I'm having trouble doing something similar with javascript

```
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
    x="SomeValue";
    div.setAttribute("id", (x));
    div.setAttribute("onMouseDown", "SomeFunction((x))");
```

where obviously I want x to be "SomeValue", but every time I look at the output, it just says x instead of the value.

Comment: Don't set the `onmousedown` attribute, instead use `div.onmousedown = function...` or `div.addEventListener('mousedown', function...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change...

```
"SomeFunction((x))"
```

to...

```
"SomeFunction((" + x + "))"
```

JavaScript doesn't support string interpolation of variables.

Comment: @Amber yikes, I'm sorry about that. I meant "her" :p